# A few questions on a probability example

Tags: probability

> Compute the probability of getting two of a kind and three of a kind
>   (a "full house") when five dice are rolled.   The answer is as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let $n_i$ be the number on the $i$th die. - We shall take as the sample space the set of all the distinct ordered 5-tuples
>      $(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)$, so that $n(S) = 6^5$ .
> 2. Let the ordered pair $(i,j)$ mean that $i$ is the number that appears twice and $j$ is the number that appears three times. The
>      number of the distinct ordered pairs, therefore, is  ${P^6_2}$
> 3. Given a particular $(i.j)$, we can choose two dice out of five which show $i$: there are ${C^5_2}$ way to do so.
>
> Hence, the desired probability P is given by:
>
> $$P=\frac{P^6_2·C^5_2}{6^5}$$

To consolidate my understanding, I extend the question myself to what if:
1) seven dive are rolled
2) then what's the probability of getting three of a kind; two of and kind and another two of a kind?

Follow the logic of the textbook, I did

1. $n(S)=6^7$
2. ordered pair $(i,j,k)$ hence $P^6_3$
3. given a particular pair, there are $\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}$ way to distribute

If the above is correct, I would expect the probability to be:
$$P=\frac{P^6_3·{\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}}}{6^7}$$, but I am not sure whether it is correct...
Also, are there other ways to approach this question?

Comment: 2).  Is not as $(i,j,k)$ and $(i,k,j)$ are the same.  $i$ is the three of a kind number, but $j,$ and $k$ are the two two of a kind number and the order does not matter.  So it is $6*C_2^5$.

Comment: 1 and 3 are correct.  2) is not but $6*C_2^5$ is.  But what is your conclusion?  What *is* the final probability.

Comment: @fleablood I have updated my post.... In that case $P=\frac{6*C^5_2*{\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}}}{6^7}$?